# Как оставлять след на поверхностях в unity2d

Tags: unity3d

Создаю 2D игру на unity. Подскажите пожалуйста как оставлять следы за персонажем на разных поверхностях? Похожий эффект был играх super meat boy и mad dex.

Answer (score 1):

если вы имеете в виду след по типу следов на снегу, то вам поможет следующий [видос](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcKjhpE5-nw&t=1171s), благо он на русском.
если вы имеете в виду след пл типу хвоста, то знакомьтесь с Trail Renderer. Полезные ссылки на эту тему: [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html) и [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TcEfIXpmRI).
Удачи

Comment: Спасибо большое